# Run `tmutil isexcluded` recursively

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, timemachine

I'd like to use `tmutil` recursively to list all of the files currently excluded from Time Machine backups. I know that I can determine this for a single file with

```
tmutil isexcluded /path/to/file
```

but I can't seem to get this to run recursively. I have tried grepping for the excluded files and outputting to a file like this:

```
tmutil isexcluded * | grep -i excluded >> ~/Desktop/TM-excluded.txt
```

but this only outputs data for the top level of the current directory. Can I use `find` or a similar command to feed every file/directory on the machine to `tmutil isexcluded` and pull out a list of the excluded files? What is the best way to structure the command?

I'm aware that most of the exclusions can be found in

`/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist`

and that some app-specific exclusions are searchable via

```
sudo mdfind "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'"
```

but I am looking for a way to compare the actual flags on the files to these lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find /starting/place -exec tmutil isexcluded {} + | grep -F "[Excluded]" | sed -E 's/^\[Excluded\][[:space:]]*//'
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `tmutil` allows you to pass multiple filenames, so I use `+` at the end of the `find` instead of `;` then I don't have to execute a new process for every single file on your machine - which could be slow. The `grep` looks for the fixed (`F`) string `[Excluded]` and the `sed` removes the `[Excluded]` and following 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the files in any subdirectory of `/path/to/master/dir` with

```
find /path/to/master/dir -type f
```

Now you cannot pipe the output to `tmutil`, so what you can do is

```
find /path/to/master/dir -type f -exec tmutil isexcluded {} \;
```

What this does is:

- We know what `find /path/to/master/dir -type f` does.
- `-exec` will execute anything after it.
- `{}` will use each file from `find`'s output separately with `tmutil isexcluded`.
- `\` ends the `-exec` so the `-exec` knows what command should execute (in case you would want to do something else after it).